# $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \implies \frac{y^T (X^TX) y}{y^Ty} \ge \sigma_n(X)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I came across an expression in a book on matrix computations that is not clear to me. Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be nonsingular. Then we have

$y \in \mathbb{R}^n \implies \frac{y^T (X^TX) y}{y^Ty} \ge \sigma_n(X)^2$.

I do not see how this is obvious? What identity is being used here?

Comment: With $\signa_n(X)$ do you mean the maximal or minimal eigenvalue of $X$?

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco It's the smallest singular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma_1(X) \ge \cdots\ge\sigma_n(X)$ are the singular values of $X$, then $\sigma_1(X)^2 \ge \cdots \ge \sigma_n(X)^2 \ge 0$ are the eigenvalues of $X^t X$. Write, as $X^tX$ is symmetric, $X^t X = Q^t \Sigma Q$, with $Q^t = Q^{-1} \in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbf R)$, $\Sigma = \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1(X)^2, \ldots,\sigma_n(X)^2)$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
   y^t(X^tX)y &= y^tQ^t \Sigma Qy\\
              &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(X)^2(y^tQ^t)_i(Qy)_i\\ 
              &\ge \sigma_n(X)^2 y^tQ^tQy\\
              &= \sigma_n(X)^2 y^ty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent, makes sense now thanks! I have a follow on question that is kind of a generalization of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708512/y-in-mathbbs-0-implies-fracyt-xt-a-x-yyty-ge-lambda-ka